# Pass function with 2D array input to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, 2d

I want to pass a function to a function, in which case the passing function has 2D arrays for input.

For 1D arrays I have done like that:

```
void bungee(double Y[], double DY[])
{
   // ...
}

void euler(void(ODES)(double[], double[]), double A[], double STEP)
{
   // ...

   ODES(A, B);
}

int main()
{
    // ...

    euler(bungee, y, dt);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I would like to pass bungee to euler with 2D arrays input, like this:

```
void bungee(double Y[][], double DY[][])
{ // ... }

void euler(void(ODES)(double[][], double[][])/*,...*/)
{ // ... }

int main()
{ 
    euler(bungee);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you do that ? What error do you get ?

Answer (score 1):

in C/C++, arrays will be converted to pointer when passing to function. double Y[] will be same as double *Y.

For two dimentional arrays, you must provide the inner dimension when passing to function.

Because if you pass double Y[][], it will be converted to double (*Y)[], which is an incomplete type.

Instead, double Y[][50], will be converted to double (*Y)[50], which is fine.

For N dimentional array, you must provide the inner N-1 dimensions.

For example, double Y[][10][20][30].

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. :D
So I did:
`const int DIM 50;
void bungee(double Y[][DIM], double DY[][DIM])
{ //... }

void euler(void(SYS)(double[][DIM], double[][DIM]))
{ // ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Like user534498 explained for continuous arrays, e.g.

```
void bungee(double [][50]);

void main()
{
    double array[100][50];
    bungee(array);
}
```

but if you create your 2D arrays like this

```
double **arr = new double* [100];
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    arr[i] = new double [50];
```

you must use

```
void bungee(double **);
```